# Split cursor in Mac OS High Sierra in fullscreen mode

Tags: high-sierra, trackpad, fullscreen

Recently my cursor often is split in fullscreen mode. I then basically have 2.5 cursors. Since I cannot screenshot the cursor I attached a photo. I am using the trackpad. Is anyone else experiencing this? How can I fix it? It kind of undermines the trust in my work machine :)

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017)
- Mac OS 10.13.6 (17G65)

[image]